# USB booting possible using UEFI on my laptop? HP 8460p with latest BIOS/firmware

Tags: boot, uefi

If I enable UEFI on my laptop, there's no option to boot using USB (using the boot order to determine this).

On BIOS boot, many options are available like SDcard, upgrade bay, network and etc.

On UEFI, I can only see upgrade bay, network and "OS Manager" (whatever this means).

Thank you

Comment: Many older laptops have horrible experimental UEFI support. Mine doesn't support anything but internal HDD

Comment: usb needs to be uefi bootable too. what are you trying to boot and how did you prepare that media?

Answer (score 2):

As this is a laptop from 2011 with experimental UEFI, it boots Windows by default if it's installed and `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` is present. This is because the path to this file is hardcoded in the UEFI.

Some HP models appear to have an option to edit this path, called "Customized Boot", according to the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HP_EliteBook_840_G1#UEFI_Setup). But this is not the case for the Elitebook 8460p, even with the latest firmware update.

There are two ways to "forcefully" boot other systems in UEFI mode (either from HDD or USB) when MS Windows is installed:

- One is to press <kbd>F9</kbd> to load the boot menu, and then select the option "Boot from EFI File". From there you can navigate to the proper file ending in `.efi` and load it.
- The other is to replace Windows' `bootmgfw.efi` with your own EFISTUB (always a good idea to create a backup first) - for instance, `grubx64.efi`. This allows for dual booting in UEFI mode on this laptop. Remember you may need to repeat this if you update GRUB or if it's reverted by a Windows update.

More:

[How do I get my HP laptop to boot into grub from my new efi file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/244261/495331)

[About EFI UEFI #The ESP](https://wiki.mageia.org/en/About_EFI_UEFI#The_ESP)

[Installation - HP Full UEFI Install (CloudReady)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7pVjf32-Wo)

Answer (score 1):

BIOS-based computers booted "whole disks" -- or more precisely, the BIOS could load the first sector (aka the Master Boot Record, or MBR) of a disk to run boot loader code stored there. This made for some relatively simple boot management at the firmware level -- you set a default boot device in the firmware setup utility and you could usually override that on a boot-by-boot basis by using a BIOS boot manager. The details of how to do both of these things varied from one computer to another.

With EFI/UEFI, it's more complex. EFI boots from *files,* most of which are stored on an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which is a partition with a specific type code that uses a FAT filesystem. A single ESP can theoretically hold thousands of boot loaders, although just one or two (perhaps with some support programs) is more typical. The computer knows which boot loader to run because that information is stored in NVRAM in a prioritized boot list. This boot list can sometimes be manipulated in the firmware setup utility, similar to how you'd set the boot disk priority in BIOS; and you can usually override it on a boot-by-boot basis with the firmware's built-in boot manager. As with BIOS, the details of how to set the default or enter the boot manager vary from one computer to another; but it's usually done with a keypress at boot time -- typically Esc, Enter, or a function key.

Removable media pose a special challenge to EFI-style booting. Because pointers to boot loaders are stored in NVRAM, you can't put a boot loader on a removable disk using an arbitrary filename and expect it to be booted. Thus, a standard *fallback filename* is used for removable media. For AMD64/x86-64/x64 systems, this filename is `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. Many EFIs don't generate entries for removable media unless and until they're inserted in the computer. Thus, these entries may not appear in the default boot order list you see in the firmware, just in the boot manager menu if and when you enter it. My hunch is that this is your problem; it sounds like you're trying to edit the default boot order, when instead you should be entering the boot manager menu to select the bootable medium.

Also, if an external medium lacks a fallback boot loader, that medium might not show up as a bootable device, even in the boot manager menu. Some tools for creating bootable USB drives were written before EFIs became common, and so may omit the EFI boot loader files. Some source files (`.iso` files or whatnot) may lack the EFI boot loader files, too, particularly for OSes that don't support EFI-mode booting.

Finally, you might be running into problems because of security settings. If your computer is configured to require Secure Boot, and if the boot medium doesn't support this, then you might not see a relevant boot entry, or that boot entry might not work. A few EFIs (Acers, I hear, are like this) have particularly obnoxious Secure Boot menus that require jumping through extra hoops even to boot media with properly-signed boot loader files.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer.  I know this question is getting long in the tooth, but I'm replying for anyone who might still come along after me.  There is a LOT of bad info regarding booting via USB on HP laptops introduced before UEFI became commonplace.  The comments on the OP are proof of this lack of good info and understanding. Enable UEFI, insert USB, power up and press f9, select Boot Frm EFI File, nav to EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.  Just installed Win10 on Elitebook 8460p this way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've heard UEFI is effectively a more advanced version/replacement of BIOS. The difficulty is that in general a smaller subset of technology is bootable via UEFI then when compared with BIOS (mainly in the use of 'Secure Boot' technology. I've heard cynical stories about UEFI being used as a means of locking out alternative Operating Systems such as Linux and BSD for this very reason).

http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2034007/laptop-booting-bootable-usb-drive-solved.html

https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/03/windows-10-to-make-the-secure-boot-alt-os-lock-out-a-reality/

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/bios-uefi-setup-guide-boot-from-cd-dvd-usb-drive-sd-card/

https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

Based on what I've been reading online your machine doesn't seem to be much different from others with UEFI. Basically, any device which you want to alternatively boot off of needs to be compliant with the way it works. Else, there needs to be a chain loader of some sort which loads what you want once it hits the 'OS Manager'. Obviously, if you can't achieve the previous it's quite simply a no go and reversion to standard BIOS operation may be your only choice

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Boot-and-Lockup/elitebook-8460p-will-not-boot-from-USB/td-p/5853142

Of course, this rules out the possibility of hacked UEFI which I've heard stories about. Some people have figured out a way to overcome some of the limitations that are imposed the OEM UEFI. This may be a possibility but I'm doubtful.

Obviously, it feels like you want to try alternative Operating Systems. Another option is to use a Virtualisation program such as VMWare or VirtualBox. This allows you to boot what you want though you'll be limited to what that particular environment provides you with

Comment: EFI/UEFI is a *replacement* for BIOS, not an "advanced version of BIOS." As such, the transition to EFI can be bumpy, but the cynical claims that it's a way to lock out alternative OSes are wrong. (At least so far; there's always the possibility of something more sinister in the pipeline.) Most EFI problems are due to either bugs or user misunderstandings.

Comment: EFI/UEFI is an intel brain damage. it's only "advantage" is that it keeps microsoft in, and others out - by design. Other than that, it's just a source of error and pain, and no real improvement over BIOS - in fact, actually UEFI is worse than BIOS.

Comment: Whoo, boy..."UEFI is worse than BIOS" is the most bullheaded, wrong, uninformed thing I have heard on the EUC front in a long time.  "Those new metal horses are awful things!  They are just a way to keep you from keeping a horse!  I'll never own one!"